# Keep Activity running in background

Tags: android, android-service

I have a counter app. It counts things over a long period of time(2-3hrs). During the majority of the time, for 10-15, maybe 30 minute increments), the app remains in power down state in my pocket. After this long duration Android decides i am not using it and shuts it down. So i lose all my counts.

What is best way to keep activity open in background? I was noticing the use of either wakelock, which I don't want to do because of unnecessary battery drain, and services, which would be good, i have no problem operating a service in the background.

Can services update particular interface objects of the activity, basically can it update the count on my counter screen?

and will the service prevent android from shutting down my app? I assume i can battle this by doing something like this...

```
@Override
public void onCreate(){
    ....
    if(myService.isRunning())
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MyCounterActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

That should start my activity back if android shuts it down while running the service. But then how can i get info from the service back to the counter visuals?

*Edit*
I decided to go with the sharedPreferences recommendation. so to do this i would need something like the following?

SharedPreference Singleton

```
public class MySharedPreference {   
    private static MySharedPreference mySharedPreference;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    public static MySharedPreference getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mySharedPreference == null) {
            mySharedPreference = new mySharedPreference(context);
        }
        return mySharedPreference;
    }

    private mySharedPreference(Context context) {
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(MyConstants.PREF_FILE_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public void saveData(String key,String value) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        prefsEditor .putString(key, value);
        //prefsEditor.commit(); 
        prefsEditor.apply();
    }

    public String getData(String key) {
        if (sharedPreferences!= null) {
           return sharedPreferences.getString(key, "");
        }
        return "";         
    }
}
```

Activity.class

```
@Override
public void onCreate(){


    SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener;
    listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
        if(key.compareTo(MyConstants.PREF_FIELD_M20_COUNT)){
            m20CountTextView.setText(String.format("$1%d", prefs.getInt(key, 0)));
        }else if(key.compareTo(MyConstants.PREF_FIELD_M30_COUNT)){
            m30CountTextView.setText(String.format("$1%d", prefs.getInt(key, 0)))
        }
      }
    };

    MySharedPreference.getInstance().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            m20Count++;
            MySharedPreferences.getInstance().saveData(MyConstants.PREF_FIELD_M20_COUNT, m20Count);
        }

    });

    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            m30Count++;
            MySharedPreferences.getInstance().saveData(MyConstants.PREF_FIELD_M30_COUNT, m30Count);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    updateInterfaceWithPreferences();
}

private void updateInterfaceWithPreferences(){
    m20CountTextView.setText(String.format("$1%d", MySharedPreferences.getInstance().getInt(MyConstants.PREF_FIELD_M20_COUNT, 0)));
    m30CountTextView.setText(String.format("$1%d", MySharedPreferences.getInstance().getInt(MyConstants.PREF_FIELD_M30_COUNT, 0)));
}
```

Will this work to save my data and restore it when re-entering the activity that gets shutoff.

Comment: store count in shared preference

Comment: yes you can update UI from service. Even if the app is destroyed the service will works fine. But service will keep draining your battery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use service that will run in background and will modify your **counter** .
And make that counter available to Activity by either of ways

1. Make a `public static` variable
2. Save into shared preference

and update your activity UI from the onResume() method , So whenever your activity will came into foreground it will show you the **updated count**.

Comment: so i put stuff in sharedpreferences, then Android shuts down my app because it can. When i repress the main app button, since the app was killed, will onResume() be called or should i update during onCreate()?

Comment: yes If activity is in background (not killed ) onResume() will called ,

If activity was killed then onCreate() and onResume() both will called , So better to update UI from `onResume()`

Comment: how do i use the listener to determine what pref was changed? `onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreference pref, String key)`. Lets say i have 3 preferences would i be able to retrieve the value like this 
`count1 = pref.getInt(key, 0);` so i could do a series of if statements to find which preference got changed and do what is necessary accordingly?

Comment: How many counter you are updating? I think aal need to be updated on UI so update all (though the value is changed or not) , And if your counter is updating frequently (In your question you said its not) then use Broadcast

Answer (score 0):

You can use service to count things, and send updates via event bus or broadcast it. Then in your activity you can subscribe to this events/broadcasts in onStart() method and unsubscribe in onStop(). This will allow you update UI when activity is on screen and do not overuse battery and not update UI when the phone is locked.

And please **do not** try to save your activity when user don't need it. Be a good citizen ;)

Comment: I like this idea with broadcasting, it seems more clean. So long as i have the broadcast receiver running than android will not shut down my app because it is doing stuff, waiting for a broadcast? i am counting 9 things at a time, using shared preferences seems cumbersome when  all i want to do is update a number.

Comment: Actually you don't need to update your UI if the phone is locked, so it is ok if Android kill your activity. The main point here is that your service will be alive, and when your activity will be recreated, you'll be able to subscribe to it and continue UI updates. Also you should make your service foreground or use a lock, to be sure that Android will not touch it.

Comment: Check this - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int, android.app.Notification) for details, how to make it foreground (method startForeground(...)). Also you can use foreground notification to show counter updates.

Comment: actually i think this may not be the way to go. I was just thinking, i do not want to count things while screen is locked, i just want to be able to retrieve the info of the state before it was shutdown. But i cannot be guarenteed that onDestroy() will be given time to activate. To add a number i want to open app and use the interface. maybe sharedpreferences is the way to go, even though cumbersome.

Comment: You can also use onSaveInstanceState(...) for it.

Comment: I am doing that for orientation purposes, but from the android dev site, it said when the app gets killed there is no guarentee i will have time and if it is killed there is no more activity saved information. i will have to check into this though because i do use a service for my wear interaction. and i will have to look into the wearlistenerservice to guarentee it is tracking and updating the app accurately because i think the same issue may happen if app gets killed i will no longer be able to retain counts with my current setup

Answer (score -2):

Add this on your Activity **onCreate** method

```
 getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```